# New User - Non Programmer - Gupshup

Tags: gupshup

I am not a programmer but I am somewhat technically inclined.
I have successfully built a Gupshup web widget bot and installed on a website.
Due to my lack of programming knowledge I can not gain access of the conversation data that transpired on the chatbot. I would like to access the data for further processing/parsing so I can get the information into Zoho CRM Database Via Zapier system. Please share any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can access the conversational data

1. Logs provided by Guphsup - You can go to your dashboard and then click on the logs link corresponding to your bot.
   [image]
2. Use an analytics platform like dashbot.io - You can go through this [guide](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/integrating-dashbot-analytics-with-your-gupshup-bot) to understand how to connect dashbot and Gupshup.